# Unset a DependencyProperty for serializing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization

I'm serializing XAML to a file and reading it again (using XamlWriter and XamlReader).

If a DependencyProperty (like the Name property of a FrameworkElement) is never set for the element, then the element can be serialized and deserialized without a problem.

However, as soon as the DependencyProperty is set at some time before serialization, it is not allowed to be Null or string.Empty when being serialized (or de-serialization will throw a XamlParseException saying that a named object could not be registered because the value is not allowed to be null/empty character string).

Is there a way to effectively unset a DependencyProperty?

Thanks very much

Comment: Try return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Excellent, this worked (while setting the DependencyProperty with myFrameworkElement.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue). If you put your post in an answer I will accept it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`. Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Specifies a static value that is used by the WPF property system rather than null to indicate that the property exists, but does not have its value set by the property system.